Integrar consulta de base de datos en menu Adminlte laravel
quisiera solicitar su apoyo para integrar una consulta al config/adminlte.php
ya hice un controlador para que en mis vistas cree menus con permisos pero quiero integrarlo al menu de adminlte
Ese es el menu de config/adminlte.php
'menu' => [
// Ítems de la barra de navegación:
    ['header' => 'account_settings'],  // Encabezado de las opciones de cuenta.
    [
        'text' => 'Ajustes usuarios',  // Enlace para cambiar la contraseña.
        'url' => '',
        'icon' => 'fas fa-fw fa-users-cog',
        'submenu' => [
            [
                'text' => 'Usuarios',  // Enlace para cambiar la contraseña.
                'url' => 'users',
                'icon' => 'fas fa-fw fa-users',
                'can' => 'menu:users',
            ],
            [
                'text' => 'Roles',  // Enlace para cambiar la contraseña.
                'url' => 'roles',
                'icon' => 'fas fa-fw fa-user-secret',
                'can' => 'menu:roles',
            ],
            
            [
                'text' => 'Permisos',  // Enlace para cambiar la contraseña.
                'url' => 'permisos',
                'icon' => 'fas fa-fw fa-user-shield',
                'can' => 'menu:permisos',
            ],
        ],
    ],



],

En esta parte esta mi controlador que hice para mi menu
app\Http\Controllers\MenuController.php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Menu;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Permission;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
class MenuController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $menus = Menu::with('children')->whereNull('parent_id')->get();
        return view('menus.index', compact('menus'));
    }

    public function create()
{
    $menus = Menu::all(); // Recupera todos los menús
    return view('menus.create', compact('menus'));
}


    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'title' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'permission' => 'nullable|string',
        ]);

        Menu::create([
            'title' => $request->title,
            'url' => $request->url,
            'icon' => $request->icon,
            'permission' => $request->permission,
            'is_multilevel' => $request->has('is_multilevel'),
            'parent_id' => $request->parent_id,
        ]);

        return redirect()->route('menus.index')->with('success', 'Menú creado exitosamente.');
    }

}


quisiera ver la forma de integrar la consulta y que me imprima los menus que haga en la base de datos
estoy usando laravel 11 y adminlte para laravel de https://github.com/jeroennoten/Laravel-AdminLTE/
